# About Atiyah's proof on Zariski's lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

The proof is attached below. My question is that $A=k[x_1]$ is a finitely generated $k-$algebra, but how can we let $K$ be its field of fractions if we do not know $A$ is an integral domain or not? Any help is appreciated.

The proof is from the book 'Introduction to Commutative Algebra' by Atiyah and Macdonald.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are told $B$ is a field, so any subring of $B$ is an integral domain.

Comment: Thank you very very much. Can't believe that minute detail bothers me that much.